# Calculating decimal difference in minutes format

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have Time_In number(7,2) := 12.40

and    Time_Out number(7,2) := 23.05

and Total_Hours number(7,2)=Time_Out-Time_In

and Result will be Total_Hours=10.65 which should be 10.25

Can someone give me SQL query to calculate difference between Time_in and Time_out.

Comment: Are you doing this on MySQL, SQL Server AND Oracle? All three? If not, please EDIT your post and delete the tags that don't apply. And if you don't know what plsql is, delete that as well. (Or if you do know, and you recognize that the question has nothing to do with PL/SQL.)

Comment: Time_In and Time_Out are NUMBER datatype? What does 12.40 mean? Are you just inputting the time as a decimal number, so if the time is 12:40 you will input 12.4? Very odd!  Then - are the "times" always be guaranteed to be valid times, so you will never have 13.83 or 42.04? Are they always on the same date, and time_out always greater than or equal to time_in? Most importantly, **why are the two columns of datatype NUMBER and not the correct datatype, DATE**?

Comment: Actually I am working on a PL/SQL procedure which takes biometric data that give time_in and time_out like this ,I just need a formula to calculate the hours worked.

Comment: Perfect, then please delete the MySQL and the SQL Server tags - they may solve the same problem in very different ways from Oracle/PLSQL.

Comment: Time_out is always greater than Time_in and always less than 24.00 .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work. It's just a hack; you would do MUCH better to change the base table to store times in the DATE datatype.

The idea is, when the minutes on the time_out are less than on time_in, to subtract 1 from hours on the time_out and to add 60 minutes. This is just like subtracting 0.4 when working with decimals. So this is exactly what the solution does.

So, yes, this can be done, and it is easy to do - it is just the wrong thing to do. Good luck!

```
with 
     inputs ( time_in, time_out ) as (
       select  9.45, 12.06 from dual union all
       select 10.20, 14.02 from dual
     )
select time_in, time_out, 
       case when time_out - trunc(time_out) >= time_in - trunc(time_in)
                   then time_out - time_in
            else time_out - time_in - 0.4 end   as difference
from inputs;


TIME_IN  TIME_OUT  DIFFERENCE
   9.45     12.06        2.21
   10.2     14.32        4.12
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert the hours to fractional hours:

```
select (trunc(time_out) + (time_out - trunc(time_out)) / 60) +
        trunc(time_in) + (time_in - trunc(time_in)) / 60)
       ) as diff_in_hours

. . .
```

You can convert this back to your arcane notation.  Here is one method:

```
select trunc(diff_in_hours) + (diff_in_hours - trunc(diff_in_hours) * 60 / 100
from (select (trunc(time_out) + (time_out - trunc(time_out)) / 60) +
              trunc(time_in) + (time_in - trunc(time_in)) / 60)
             ) as diff_in_hours
      .  . .
     ) x
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select  time_out - time_in - case when mod(time_in,1) > mod(time_out,1) then 0.4 else 0 end
from    t
```

Comment: First version is much better - easy to read and understand, easy to maintain. "Self-documenting" comes to mind.

Comment: @mathguy, I agree.